# Quantity and Trig functions

Tags: trigonometry, version-9, units

I have a bunch of data to which I've assigned units using `Quantity`, including some angular measurements in degrees. I'd like to be able to use these measurements with trigonometric functions, but it seems that trig functions don't "know" about `Quantity`, so I'm forced to convert those measurements to radians and then apply the trig function to the magnitudes, like this:

```
x = Quantity[23.4, "AngularDegrees"]
Cos[QuantityMagnitude @ UnitConvert[x, "Radians"]]
```

This works, but it's slow and seems clunky, at best. Is there a more elegant (and hopefully faster) approach?

Comment: What happens if you try `x /. Quantity[a_, "AngularDegrees"] :> a °`?

Comment: Have you tried using `N`?

Comment: @J.M.: That's certainly faster--more than an order of magnitude in my quick check.

Comment: @Spawn1701D: How would I use N?

Comment: I don't have installed v9 yet so I can't verified it directly but i was thinking of something like `N[Cos[x]]`.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work, @Spawn1701D.

Comment: @DavidSkulsky ok!

Comment: @DavidSkulsky if you have time, you could look at `Trace[Cos[QuantityMagnitude @ UnitConvert[x, "Radians"]],TraceInternal->True` It seems there is at least some overhead.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, one might consider avoiding `UnitConvert[]` for this purpose:

```
lp = LatitudeLongitude[GeoPosition[{40.11, -88.26}]]
   {Quantity[40.11, "AngularDegrees"], Quantity[-88.26, "AngularDegrees"]}

RepeatedTiming[UnitConvert[lp, "Radians"]]
   {0.00018, {Quantity[0.700052, "Radians"], Quantity[-1.54043, "Radians"]}}

RepeatedTiming[lp /. Quantity[x_?NumericQ, "AngularDegrees"] :> x °]
   {0.000013, {0.700052, -1.54043}}
```

---

For converting angles in DMS format, the method is a bit more elaborate:

```
sp = StarData["Polaris", "Declination"]
   Quantity[MixedMagnitude[{89, 15, 50.76`2.1985422820612186}],
            MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}]]

sp /. Quantity[MixedMagnitude[m_],
               MixedUnit[{"AngularDegrees", "ArcMinutes", "ArcSeconds"}]] :> FromDMS[m] °
   1.55795
```

Despite the complexity, this is still faster than `UnitConvert[]`.