# Mathematica in degrees mode

Tags: trigonometry, customization

How can I tell Mathematica to evaluate all expressions, plot all functions, solve all equations in degrees, instead of radians?

Comment: [`Degree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Degree.html)?

Comment: @corey979 what does that mean?

Comment: @corey979 i mean like the option in scientific calculators.

Comment: So, you want the result of `D[Sin[x], x]` to be `π Cos[x]/180`? In the meantime: `Plot[Sin[x °], {x, 0, 360}]`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Possibly a bad idea for the reasons mentioned in previous messages, but you could do something like the following:

```
SetAttributes[trigMode, HoldAllComplete];
trigMode[expr_] := 
 Unevaluated[expr] /. 
    {(f : ArcSin | ArcCos | ArcTan | ArcCot | ArcSec | ArcCsc)[x_] :> 180 f[x]/π,
     (f : Sin | Cos | Tan | Cot | Sec | Csc)[x_] :> f[x °]};

$Pre = trigMode;

Sin[90]
(* 1 *)

ArcSin[Sqrt[3]/2]
(* 60 *)

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 360}]
```

[image: sine in degrees]

I used [`$Pre`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Pre.html) to make sure my function `trigMode` is applied to every input expression.  It was important that the function has the attribute [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete.html) (so it doesn't evaluate on me and therefore `ArcSin[Sqrt[3]/2]` doesn't get transformed to `π/3` before I have a chance to catch it and apply a transformation rule).  `trigMode` uses some pattern matching to find parts of the expression that contain "trig functions" and makes sure they get treated like a calculator in "degree mode" would.

When you want to go back to the standard mode, use `$Pre = .` to clear.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sure thing.

Comment: Done.  Please check that I did not break anything!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard looks good to me.  I knew `MemberQ` was a bad idea.

Comment: I've added the three other pairs of trig functions; it might be sufficient for students.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sin[60 Degree]
```

$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

```
Plot[Sin[alpha Degree], {alpha, 0, 360}]
```

[image]

```
ToDeg[rad_] := N[rad/Degree];
FromDeg[deg_] := N[Degree deg];

ToDeg[ArcSin[Sqrt[3]/2]]
60.
```

**See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313489/set-degrees-as-default-in-mathematica-8**

Comment: Isn't there a feature to set it in degrees without putting `Degree` after the angle so that when I input `ArcSin[Sqrt[3]/2]`, the answer will be 60?

Comment: I doubt that. Consider `ArcSin[2.]` - how do you want to express complex numbers in degrees?

Comment: @corey: I agree, and additionally, should `Exp[180 I]` be `-1`, in such a case?

Comment: @Teokan Duran Demircan: see above

Comment: Or try with `UnitConvert`.

Comment: @corey, [that's much slower](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23644).

Comment: @J.M. I don't fully get what the OP wants to accomplish, so I'm throwing ideas. Personally, for mathematical applications I don't see a reason for using degrees instead of radians; radians are great (and natural), degrees are only good for measuring temperature ;)

Comment: Certainly radians are the natural choice in math, @corey, but not everybody is a mathematician. :) Note that in *Mathematica*, one still has to specify longitude and latitude in degrees, and certain astronomical functions return in DMS format.

Comment: @corey979 and J. M. see the link above ...

Comment: @corey979 What does OP mean?

Comment: OP=original poster; see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean).